# Overridden vs. virtual class methods in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, python-2.7, inheritance

As far as I understand, in Python methods of parent class are overridden. 
So all class methods are virtual by default as can be seen from the code below.

```
class Parent(object):

    def Method1(self):
        print 'FOO'

class Child(Parent):

    def Method1(self):
        print 'BAR'

myInstance = Child()

#Overridden method is called
myInstance.Method1()                             # BAR

#Is it possible to do the following?
myInstance.{something}                           # FOO
```

**QUESTIONS:**

- Is it possible to call parent method `Parent.Method1()` from the instance `myInstance` of the child class?
- Is it possible to make `def Parent.Method1(self)` **not** to be overridden by a method with the same name, but some different set of arguments `def Child.Method1(self,x,y)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call parent methods by having the `super()` function search for the next method in the MRO (method resolution order):

```
class Child(BaseClass):
    def Method1(self):
        print 'BAR'
        super(Child, self).Method1()  # will call BaseClass.Method1
```

where `self` is the instance reference, so `super(type(myInstance), myInstance).Method1()` would achieve the same thing from outside the method.

Or you can access the unbound method on the class, and pass in the instance explicitly; you'd be able to do this outside the method too:

```
BaseClass.Method1(myInstance)
```

because now you referenced the method attribute directly on the class instead, and passed in the instance as an explicit `self` to that method; you'd use `self` from inside a method on `Child` there.

Python attributes (methods are attributes too) are looked up by name and such look-ups search through the instance, then the class of the instance, then through each parent class until a match is found; the signature of a method doesn't come into play here.

You can still override a method in a child class, change the signature, but remain *compatible* with the parent method by using keyword arguments:

```
class Child(BaseClass):
    def Method1(self, x=None, y=None):
        if x is None and y is None:
            # arguments left at defaults, call base method
            return super(Child, self).Method1()

        print 'BAR: {} and {}'.format(x, y)
```

Now if you call `myInstance.Method1()`, with no arguments, the `BaseClass.Method1()` method is called, pass in arguments and something else happens instead.

Comment: Yes, that's clear for me. I can't figure out on how to call parent method from the instance of the child class, so I may select what to call (child or parent method) in my program

Comment: @Konstantin: That is just what his code shows you how do to.

Comment: @BrenBarn, I'm not sure. That's calling of the parent method from the child class method using `super()`, no problem with it. I wanted to know is there any way for the Child's instance to invoke either its method or the method of its parent that was overriden

Comment: @Konstantin: Can you give an example of what you mean?  You can call the parent method using `super(Child, child_instance).Method1()` just the same as it's done inside a method.  I'm not sure what you mean by calling the method "from the child instance" rather than "from the child class method".

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to call parent method Parent.Method1() from the
>   instance myInstance of the child class?

You can call the method directly, and pass your instance as first argument:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def foo(self):
...         print 'foo'
...
>>> class B(A):
...     def foo(self):
...         print 'bar'
...
>>> b = B()
>>> A.foo(b)
foo
```

> Is it possible to make def Parent.Method1(self) not to be overridden
>   by a method with the same name, but some different set of arguments
>   def Child.Method1(self,x,y)?

Yes, you use [super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-and-init-methods) and call the parent's method directly:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def foo(self, bar='bar'):
...         print bar
...
>>> class B(A):
...     def foo(self):
...         super(B, self).foo(bar='foo')
...
>>> B().foo()
foo
>>> A().foo()
bar
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. Is it possible to do something like B().foo() -> calls parent method, B().foo(x,y) -> calls child method? So argument set prevents virtual function from being overridden.

Comment: Kind of. The child could define `foo` as `def foo(self, arg1=None, arg2=None)`, and if `arg1` and `arg2` are both `None` in the body, then call the parent method. The child method is always called, but *it* can then decide to call the parent method. In general, Python does not look at the arguments passed to a method to determine which function to actually call. (Which I see now is exactly what Martijn Pieters proposes in his answer.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using `super`, there are a couple of explicit options that bypass the MRO:

```
# Explicitly call Baseclass.Method1, passing your instance as the argument
BaseClass.Method1(myInstance)

# Call Method1 on the (first) base class of the instance.
# This is ugly; don't actually write code like this
# x.__class__.__bases__[0] is just another way to get a reference
# to BaseClass; otherwise, this is identical to the previous option,
# hence the need to repeat myInstance
myInstance.__class__.__bases__[0].Method1(myInstance)
```